# How to lock code execution in iOS application

Tags: c++, ios, cocoa-touch, locking, nslock

### Problem Description

I have a function `StdString ShowLockScreen()` in this function I call `activateViewController` function which shows some UI where user must enter PIN, just after calling `activateViewController` function I want to lock all processes until user will enter his PIN and press OK button on opened UI. Below you can see code which I try

### Source code in iOS

```
StdString ShowLockScreen() 
{
    // Create a lock.
    NSLock* theLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
    // Create a UI in which user must enter his PIN.
    PinLockController* controller = [[PinLockController alloc] initWithStyle:PinLockTypeSet];
    // Set delegate. 
    controller.delegate = m_Context;

    // !!! Here I show a UI and just after that I lock my lock in order code stop executing there.
    [controller activateViewController:nil];

    @synchronized(theLock) {
        [theLock lock];
    }

    NSLog(@"User in UI unlock the lock");
}
```

I want that my code stops then I call `[theLock lock];` and after I will call [theLock unlock]; from my UI and code will continue executing. But it doesn't work in my case.

### Source code in Android

I have write similar application in Android and here is code. I want to write same in iOS but I can;t find solution

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, SoftPinActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

SharedObject lock = new SharedObject("");
int lockId = SharedObject.acquireLockId(lock);
Logger.i(TAG, "lockId = " + lockId);
intent.putExtra(SharedObject.LOCK_ID, lockId);
intent.putExtra(SoftPinActivity.UI_ID, style);

synchronized (lock) {
   mCtx.startActivity(intent);
   try {
          Logger.i(TAG, "lock.wait()...");
          lock.wait();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          Logger.i(TAG, "InterruptedException");
   }
}
Logger.i(TAG, "lock.wait()...done");
SharedObject.releaseLockId(lockId);

String pin = lock.object();
```

### Researches

I think I must use

```
NSCondition* condLock = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
[condLock wait];
```

and

```
[condLock signal];
```

but how to use this in my code ?

Comment: When you say "lock all processes" do you actually mean you want to prevent all processes from running on the device until your app allows them to?  I'd be surprised if any modern OS allowed that, and I don't want you to do that on my device, please.

Comment: @Martin no I just to want lock my process, and open new UI when enter pin in new UI and unlock the lock...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found solution to this issue, below you can see implemented function and line by line description.

```
StdString ShowLockScreen() 
{
    // Create NSCondition lock object.
    NSCondition* conditionLock = [[NSCondition alloc] init];

    // Here I create my UI which must ask user to enter PIN.
    PinLockController* controller = [[PinLockController alloc] initWithStyle:PinLockTypeSet];
    controller.delegate = m_Context;

    // Here I lock the thread but not main thread (this is very important) I start
    // ShowLockScreen function in new thread and lock it.
    [conditionLock lock];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // I call function which shows my UI in main thread as UI can be shown 
        // only in MAIN THREAD. (This is important too.)
        [controller ShowLockController:conditionLock];
    });

    // Then I set lock to wait, how you can see I pass conditionLock as an 
    // argument to ShowLockController function in that function when user
    // enter his PIN and press okay button I call [conditionLock signal];
    // and my code code here after wait and continue executing.
    [conditionLock wait];

    NSLog(@"Come here then I call [conditionLock signal]!!!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to problem

You can lock threads using `NSLock`, but in your situation, this doesn't seem to be applicable. The reason being is that locking is primarily used to provide thread safety when data is accessed from multiple threads. What you're asking for is a domain level lock, which prevents the user from using the application unless they've typed in their PIN. These two concepts share the word "lock", but they're entirely different in their implementation. If you were to use `NSLock` and its related counterparts, you're forcing your implementation into separate threads purely to block user interaction, and risk complicating your project and pains in debugging (deadlocks much?).

### Suggested solution

As the concept is a domain level locking mechanism, I suggest we keep it this way for its implementation. If you want it to be analogous to Android, then you'd need to create your own concept of a 'SharedObject' that everything else queries. If this object were to say "The user hasn't unlocked the application", then nothing will process. This keeps you away from manually managing threads, and frees threads up for when you really need them most (asynchronous processing for example).

To implement this object, lets call it a `UserContext`, which is available as a singleton. How to implement this sharedInstance [can be seen here](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/12/19/fundamental-ios-design-patterns-sharedinstance-singleton-objective-c/).

Once you have that, then you can add various properties to it that are global throughout the application (and by the suggestion of the name, has all global properties that belong to a particular user). One of these properties is whether the user has the app locked or not:

```
[[UserContext sharedInstance] isLocked] // Returns BOOL
```

Using this throughout your application, you can then control (at the domain concept level), whether a method can compute something or not (naturally, you'll need to make `UserContext` thread safe, as it could be queried anywhere at any time). It would make it clear to the developer reading the code, that a certain method can not do anything unless the user has unlocked the app. To stop

### Side notes

> I want that my code stops then I call `[theLock lock];` and after I will call `[theLock unlock];` from my UI and code will continue executing.

**Do not, under any circumstances, lock the UI thread.** In a published app, the watchdog will kill your app, and it will effectively crash.

Answer (score 0):

ViTo, as much I concerned with the NSLock, we use it in the case of multi-threading in which we lock a particular thread and force that upto that not unlock, none other thread become active or to do his required task.
So, may be what we can do that first of all we start all of your processes in the terms of thread and at that point when you try to open your UI we call 'lock' and when user pressed the button after inputting the text-box then we call 'unlock'.
But, for this we've to sure that this thread has high priority.
That's what I'm thinking right now, but really try this with my sample code and will update you accordingly.

***Check that part of code:***

```
+(void)aMethod:(id)param{
 int x;
 for(x=0;x<50;++x)
 {enter code here
 [lock lock];
 printf("Object Thread says x is %i\n",x);
 usleep(1);
 [lock unlock];
 }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
 int x;
 lock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(aMethod:) toTarget:[MViewController class] withObject:nil]; 
 for(x=0;x<50;++x)
 {
 [lock lock];
 printf("Main thread says x is %i\n",x);
 usleep(10000);
 printf("Main thread lets go %i\n",x);
[lock unlock];
 usleep(100);
 }
 printf("Now getting the process");
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Check the log you'll get what you want.
Hope, it's what you need. For any concern, shout-over me.

Comment: I will wait, can you provide example too ?

Comment: Vito, have you go through my solution? Actually, as much I think in the case of pThread, conditionLock is used when we have a specific condition to meet in order to unlock the lock but as I check your code, I found the same miss so please tell me.

Comment: you see NSLock do not have wait method, so it can't be used in my case.

Comment: Yeah, but where you're unlocking ?

Comment: I unlock in other UI, I lock thread show UI then from they UI then user press OK unlock thread and notify it. thats all